# correcto uso de bignumbers.js. operaciones sathosis

Tags: javascript

tengo algun proyecto el cual me toca hacer operacion con muchos decimales, exactamente con cryptomonedas, la cual se me ha echo muy dificil de hacer, estoy intentado usar la libreria [bignumber.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) pero no tengo muy claro su correcto uso.

```js
let z = (x) => console.log(x);

let a = new BigNumber(0.00000069)
let b = 0.00000070
let c = 0.00000009

// SUMA
// con decimales
z(a.plus(b));
// sin decimales
z(a.plus(c));

// RESTA
// sin decimales
z(a.minus(b))
z(a.minus(c))

// MULTIPLICACION
z(a.multipliedBy(b))
z(a.multipliedBy(c))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/8.1.1/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

Viendo el codigo de arriba practicamente ejecuto la primera suma correctamente, es decir como lo deseo, mantiene los 8 decimales, pero ya la siguiente suma no me sale, que estoy haciendo mal, soy una total novata de esta libreria, pero es evidente que algo falta por hacer.

Como hacer para hacer operaciones correctamente con esta cantidad de decimales?

Alguna otra libreria que pueda llevar a cabo dichas operaciones?

Gracias chicos. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La librería funciona correctamente. Las operaciones se realizan con **todos** los decimales. Tu problema está **al mostrarlos**, no al operar con ellos.

Tomado de la propia página que indicas:

> **toFixed( )**
>   
>    Returns a string representing the value of this BigNumber in normal (fixed-point) notation rounded to dp decimal places using rounding mode rm.
>   
>   If the value of this BigNumber in normal notation has fewer than dp fraction digits, the return value will be appended with zeros accordingly.
>   
>   Unlike Number.prototype.toFixed, which returns exponential notation if a number is greafter or equal to 10<sup>21</sup>, this method will always return normal notation.
>   ...

Lo importante es el último párrafo:

> A diferencia de `Number.prototype.toFixed`, que usa notación exponencial para valores superiores a 10<sup>21</sup>, este método **siempre usará notación normal**.

```js
let z = (x) => console.log(x);

let a = new BigNumber(0.00000069)
let b = 0.00000070
let c = 0.00000009

// SUMA
// con decimales
z(a.plus(b).toFixed( ) );
// sin decimales
z(a.plus(c).toFixed( ) );

// RESTA
// sin decimales
z(a.minus(b).toFixed( ) )
z(a.minus(c).toFixed( ) )

// MULTIPLICACION
z(a.multipliedBy(b).toFixed( ) )
z(a.multipliedBy(c).toFixed( ) )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bignumber.js/8.1.1/bignumber.min.js"></script>
```

> 0.00000139
>   0.00000078
>   -0.00000001
>   0.0000006
>   0.000000000000483
>   0.0000000000000621

Comment: estupendo, muchas gracias :)